# What is Vitaly Petrov's racing number?

Tags: cars-2

I never got a chance to see Vitaly Petrov's number in [*Cars 2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1216475/). However, given the attention to detail that is given in this movie, I very much doubt that he hasn't been assigned one. Can you help me? My son would be very grateful.

This is the car I'm asking about:

[image: This is the car I'm asking about]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure he *has* a number.

[This page](http://pixar.wikia.com/World_Grand_Prix_Racers) lists all the World Grand Prix Racers from the films, each of whom has a colour scheme and a number. This list includes people like Lewis Hamilton (No. 2) and Francesco Bernoulli (No. 1).

However, [this other Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Cars_characters#World_Grand_Prix_Racers) lists the racers in slightly more detail. For Jeff Gorvette (No. 24) it states:

> The character does not appear in international versions of Cars 2. In
>   two scenes (one where Lightning meets him at the party in Tokyo, and
>   another when that scene appears in Mater's nightmare), Gorvette is
>   replaced by a completely different character, voiced by a regionally
>   better known racer than Jeff Gordon. Most of them share the body shape
>   with Max Schnell and the least of them share after the body of Miguel
>   Camino:
>
> Mark Winterbottom as Frosty (Australian release)
>   Fernando
>   Alonso as Fernando Alonso (Spanish release)
>   **Vitaly Petrov as Vitaly
>   Petrov (Russian release)**
>   Jan Nilsson as Flash (Swedish release)
>   Unknown as Long Ge (Chinese release)
>   Memo Rojas as Memo Rojas, Jr.
>   (Mexican release)
>   Sebastian Vettel as Sebastian Schnell (German
>   release)
>   Claudia Leitte as Carla Veloso (Brazilian release)
>   Unknown as Raoul ÇaRoule (French release)

No number is listed. Some further searching led me to [this site](http://www.toywiz.com/cars2diecast.html), which is one of many selling toy replicas of the cars in the films. Unlike most of the other racers, *no number* is listed against Vitaly's entry, or his picture:

[image]

Additionally, stills from the film show nothing:

[image]

Therefore, I think it's safe to assume he most likely *doesn't have* a racing number, as he is only feature in one country's version of the film.

Comment: I've reluctantly downvoted. The Disney character page for Vitaly Petrov clearly shows a number

Answer (score 1):

The [official Disney.co.uk page for Vitaly Petrov](http://www.disney.co.uk/cars/characters/vitaly-petrov) shows the following image. His number was apparently **11**.

[image]

> *Vitaly Petrov is the first and only Russian race car ever to compete
>   in the Formula World Championship. He didn't start off as a Formula
>   racer though. In fact, there was very little motorsport in Vitaly's
>   hometown of Vyborg Russia, so he got most of his race training in
>   rally sprints and ice races. After winning the Russian Rally Sprint
>   title, he won every race in the Russian Lada Cup. Vitaly was soon on
>   his way to the top with multiple Formula wins. With all his speed and
>   success, it's no wonder Vitaly became known as the Vyborg Rocket.*

Comment: FYI: The writing below his number reads Виталии Петров which I am reliably informed (by google) means "*Vitaly Petrov*"